# app closes due to memory issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory

My app closes itself during syncing process whenever it has to download lots of images.

It works perfectly fine with emulator, but when I run it on device it closes after downloading few images with "terminated due to memory issue" warning in console.

If I reduce the number of images to download, it work fine on device.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Show code how you download and retrieve the image.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, except all of my images are embedded within my application. Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

These might happen because of memory issue. Your simulator is running on mac PC. So app can easily run without memory problem. But device cannot handle this issue due to its memory.

According to your case, your are doing heavy task.

1. Main things, you have to run the download task in async background threads. Use `NSURLSessionDownloadTask`
2. Try to reduce the original quality image, so you can achieve little faster.
3. Go to Xcode and select `"show the debug navigator (left side) and check Memory and Energy Impact"`. Now run the app and do the same. This will help you to identify the app memory and energy used.
4. `Instruments` helps you to monitor your app where exactly its crashing.
5. Check the crash report which you will get in `"Windows->Devices->Select your device on left side -> View Device Logs"` then select the latest crash logs of your app.

Comment: HI, i am running download task in async background threads, but the app is still closing. i think the OS kill the app because of memory issue. any other work around i can do to solve this?

Comment: @Shelby I'm having the same problem, except all of my images are embedded within my application. Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Hi, I think you cant do much about it, I don't know why Apple makes it so complex. anyways, I have sorted my issue by reducing the image sizes, less memory =  faster download process. Also, see if it is feasible for you to use  "beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler" method, and put your sync code in this method, this will block the thread for 3mins and your  app will work even in the background without OS closing it for 3mins(Use only if it is feasible for you). cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you're storing the images that you downloaded in memory you will eventually run out of memory.

Perhaps a better approach is to cache each image you download and not hold all of them in memory.

There's a few libraries to help you out with this,

Objective-C: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage 
https://github.com/path/FastImageCache  Swift:https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift

Answer (score 0):

In Simulator, it has enough memory to stored data and its using computer's speed. So you didn't get any issue. When you tried to do the same thing into Device, its very limit space.

Image downloading process is the same which take lots of memory and process. There are many chances we are download image every time. You need to stored image into catch memory and second time, you need to retrieve from it.

You can use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) for this.

**Objective-C:**

```
    #import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
    ...
    [imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"imagepath"]
                 placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

**Swift:**

```
import SDWebImage

imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "imagepath"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```